# Join MySQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I would like my SELECT statement to select records from table A, but only those that are attached to category ID that equals for example '57' and reside in table B. Both tables are linked by the column CHANNEL ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User INNER JOIN between tables

SELECT *  FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.CHANNEL_ID = B.CHANNEL_ID 
AND CATEGORY_ID = 57

refer the below link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp